# Symfony 1.4 installation and security issues

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a shared hosting account in which I want to install my symfony 1.4 and deploy and application. I bumped into some issues because of the  **inability** to **change** the **apache** **config** on the production server.

the structure of my web server is:

```
hosting_account_name   
  html                        <--- public folder
```

I then moved all files in symfony local app folder to my **hosting_account_name** and put the web folder content in **html**

So i got the following structure:

```
   hosting_account_name   
      apps
      cache
      config
      data
      html
          css
          js
          index.php
          .htaccess
          frontend_dev.php
      lib
      log
      plugins
      test
```

and i added the line bellow to config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php
$this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/www');

I have a couple of issues though:
1. when i access the frontend_dev.php no images are due to the fact that symfony expects some files to be under a sf/ folder. Should I move the files there?
2. Index.php gives an error. Even with display errors set to yes and 500 internal server error is presented.

Also i had to set my permissions to 777 on cache and log. Their are under the folder html so that's ok for security right?

Comment: Make sure you remove the dev front controllers after your initial testing, or at least check if they `die()` correctly. If they're left there and they allow access to your system, that's a huge information leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you said that the "public" folder is `html`, but you used `$this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/www');`. Is it `html` or `www`? (Just to make sure)

Then: setting the `sf_web_dir` should work like you expected, so that shouldn't throw any errors.

To link the `/sf` Symfony folder,  you will need to add something to your apache configuration. As described on the [first page](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01) of the Jobeet tutorial, you will need to add an Alias to the `/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf`.
If you don't have access to the `httpd.conf`, you could also add this to your `.htaccess`.

777 for log and cache is ok. It's what the default `project:permissions` task does as well.

Comment: Alternatively he may simlink/copy the sf folder in the webroot.